# Typescript - Recursive Function Type

Tags: typescript, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive typescript family of functions that takes an array with elements of its own type as a parameter.

```
function example(parameter:number, path: {(parameter:number, path:{/*what do I put here?!*/}[]):boolean;}[]) : boolean
{
    return false;
}
```

This means I could call the function with:

```
let result = example(123, [example, example, anotherexample]);
```

The path / "What do I put here" part is where I'm stuck. I'd like to put the whole function type into a typedef somehow, also to improve readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the type of `example` as an interface, so you can refer to it in the type for `path`:

```
interface Example {
  (parameter: number, path: Example[]): boolean
}

function example(parameter: number, path: Example[]): boolean {
  return false;
}
```

[demo on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(parameter%3A%20number%2C%20path%3A%20Example%5B%5D)%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example(parameter%3A%20number%2C%20path%3A%20Example%5B%5D)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20example(123%2C%20%5Bexample%2C%20example%5D)%3B%0D%0A)

UPD: To explicitly declare the type of `example`, you can write it like this:

```
const example : Example = function (parameter: number, path: Example[]): boolean {
  return false;
}
```

This will warn for type errors, but note that it's a constant now, so you won't be able to refer to it before its declaration. For more info on interfaces, check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm new to typescript, so I wasn't sure how to write an interface for just a function type, and your answer has helped me greatly.

Small follow-up: Is there a way to declare and define "function example" based on this type? (maybe more trouble tan what it's worth).

    `let example : Step = /* what now? */`